# Unable to edit data array in plugin behavior

Tags: cakephp, plugins, behavior

My plugin behavior is reading the data array, doing everything it is supposed to, but nothing happens to the array in my controller, it stays the same.

Controller code:

```
if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    $this->request->data['Task']['id'] = $task['Task']['id'];
    if($this->Task->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
        debug($this->request->data);exit;
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $slug));
    }
    $this->setFlash(__('TASK_EDIT_FAILED'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $slug));
}
```

Behavior code:

```
public function beforeSave (Model $Model, $options = array()) {
    App::import('Model', 'Upload.Attachment');
    $this->Attachment = new Attachment();
    if(isset($Model->data[$Model->alias]['Attachment'])) {
        foreach($Model->data[$Model->alias]['Attachment'] as $key => $attachment) {
            $data['Attachment'] = $attachment;
            $data['Options'] = array(
                'model' => $Model->alias,
                'root' => WWW_ROOT . 'files',
            );
            $this->Attachment->create();
            $this->Attachment->save($data);
            $Model->data['Attachment']['Attachment'][$key] = $this->Attachment->getInsertID();
            unset($Model->data[$Model->alias]['Attachment'][$key]);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

Turns out `$this->request->data` in the TasksController does not change after the save, while `$this->data` in the Task model was changed (I debugged `$this->data` in the Task->afterSave() function).

Comment: You should load a model using `$this->Attachment = ClassRegistry::init('Attachment')` - no App::import etc necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that doesn't solve my problem. :)

Comment: Task. in the Task class i have set `$actsAs = array('Upload.Attachment');`

Comment: still if it didn't work let me know.

Answer (score 0):

if you wrote your behaviour inside your Task Model you do not need to do this. so remove this.

```
 $actsAs = array('Upload.Attachment');
```

also rather than this

```
if($this->Task->saveAssociated($this->request->data, array('deep' => true))) {
```

use this

```
if($this->Task->save($this->request->data, false)) {
```

if you are using cakephp 2.x rather than using

```
App::import('Model', 'Upload.Attachment');
```

use this to load an other model inside your model.

```
App::uses('Upload', 'Model');
```

Comment: 1. I need the validations, and I need recursive save. Anyway, I tried that, still no changes in the data array of the controller.
2. The behavior is part of the Upload plugin that doesn't work only for the Task model.
3. Following mark's advice, I use `$this->Attachment = ClassRegistry::init('Upload.Attachment');` now. And that is not relevant to the problem, as the attachment model is working well. My problem is the behavior not changing my data array.

Comment: did you load RequestHandler component in your app controller? - try also to load it in your Taskcontroller let me know

Comment: ok, Don't remove the RequestHandler to make sure your behaviour variable is rounding into your model and controller. Did you load App::uses('ModelBehavior', 'Model'); on top of your behaviour?

Comment: None of that worked, sorry... However, turns out `$this->request->data` in the controller is different from `$this->data` in the model... I made a debug for `$this->data` in the Task model afterSave function and the data array is modified there. So now I can move on. Thank you for your effort anyway :)